# What is the best method to add a list of objects to flink table in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a list of objects that i would like to add to a flink table. Please share how to create the table register and add the objects to the flink table.

i.e.

```
//class
class Something {
    String id:
    String firstName: 
}

//List of Something 
List<Something> somethings = new ArrayList<Something>();
```

How do i create a flink table and add each instance of the object in the list to the flink table as a new record. the table should have the columns id, first name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest solution would be to do something like this:

```
  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val tEnv =  StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
  val stream = env.fromElements(<Your elements here>) // can be also .fromCollection()
    tEnv.registerDataStream("MyTable", stream)
```

Comment: What is `FlinkTestEnv`?